# 500 Internal server error in cakePHP 2 while trying to request using ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I get 500 internal server error if try get data from another Model(Product) in Cart model. using ajax. But if I only comment out the `$this->Product->findBy(id)` is working fine.

```
$('form#add_form').on('submit', function(e){

        var thisForm = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: thisForm.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: thisForm.serialize(),
            success: function(count) {
                var total_items = $('p#total-items');
                total_items.html('Total items: ' + count);
                console.log(count);
            } 
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

this is my CartsController

```
class CartsController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Product', 'Cart');

    public function add() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $itemsInCart = $this->Session->read();

        if ($this->request->is('POST')) {
            $item = $this->Product->findBy($this->request->data['Cart']['product_id']);
        }
        echo $this->request->data['Cart']['product_id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `findby` method, you have to specify what are you [finding by](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#magic-find-types) :)

Answer (score 1):

there is no findBy method

You must change your controller code like this:

```
class CartsController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Product', 'Cart');

    public function add() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $itemsInCart = $this->Session->read();

        if ($this->request->is('POST')) {
            $productID = $this->request->data['Cart']['product_id'];
            $item = $this->Product->findById($productID);
        }
        echo json_encode($this->request->data['Cart']['product_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: error still occurs. Sir but when I i remove all the codes in add method except for $this->autoRender = false; and echo a string it will successfully return in a callback function of ajax